# IAP(in app purchase) introductory price how can I manage it iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, price

I have a set successfully implemented [IAP introductory price](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve1d49254f) for iOS, but I'm confused to whether I need any extra code on the iOS side to manage it? If so what are the required changes?

Comment: have you got the answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to implement it right, you actually need extra code. This to bring the specific offer to the customer drawing a clear understanding of what he gets.

By iOS 12 and 13, you get 3 different kind of subscription introductory price:

- free trial
- pay as you go
- pay up front

For the very significance of the three and an easy and overall view of subscriptions, refer to [Auto-renewable Subscriptions Apple doc with recommended UI](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/)

When presenting you purchase view controller, you should:

1. display the offer properly: for example: "**Start your 1-month free
   trial, then $1.99 per month**" for a free trial introductory price;
2. handle the fact that the user ALREADY benefited the introductory price in the past, therefore rather display "**Subscribe for $1.99 / month**" (to
   continue with the same example). This requires you go thru the receipts the users have and check for either "is_trial_period" or "is_in_intro_offer_period" set to true (refer to my code at the bottom of the answer).

In the Apple doc I mentioned earlier, there are many "actual" screens that show different use cases.

**My class that handles the state of introductory price per product**

```
/**
 Receipt description
 */
public class LatestReceipt: CustomStringConvertible {

    public var description: String {
        let prefix = type(of: self)
        return """
        \(prefix) expires \(expiredDate?.compact(timeStyle: .medium) ?? "nil"):
        \(prefix) • product: \(productID);
        \(prefix) • isEligible: \(isEligible);
        \(prefix) • isActive: \(isActive);
        \(prefix) • have been in free trial: \(haveBeenInFreeTrialPeriod);
        \(prefix) • intro date: \(introOfferPeriodDate?.compact(timeStyle: .medium) ?? "nil");
        \(prefix) • free trial period: \(inFreeTrialPeriod).

        """
    }


    /// Related product ID
    var productID = ""


    /**
     Tells whether the user is eligible for any introductory period

     - Note: From the Apple Doc: You can use “is_in_intro_offer_period” value to determine if the user is eligible for introductory pricing. If a previous subscription period in the receipt has the value “true” for either the “is_trial_period” or “is_in_intro_offer_period” keys, the user is not eligible for a free trial or introductory price within that subscription group.
     */
    public var isEligible = true

    /// When did the user benefited the intro offer? Nil means never.
    public var introOfferPeriodDate: Date? = nil
    /// When did the user benefited the free trial? Nil means never.
    public var freeTrialPeriodDate: Date? = nil
    public var inFreeTrialPeriod = false
    /// Tells whether the user benefited the free trial period in the past
    public var haveBeenInFreeTrialPeriod = false
    /// Is still active for today?
    public var isActive = false

    /// Last expired date
    public var expiredDate: Date? = nil

    // Latest receipt content
    public var content = NSDictionary()

    /**
     Replaces the current receipt if the new one is more recent. And compute isActive and others propteries.

     - Parameters:
        - receipt: The new receipt to test.
     */
    public func replaceIfMoreRecent(receipt: NSDictionary) {

        // Replace receipt if more recent
        if let ed = expiredDate {

            // -- Expiring product (aka subscriptions): add only the most recent
            guard let receiptExpiresDate = receipt["expires_date"] as? String,
                let red = StoreKit.getDate(receiptExpiresDate) else {
                print("\(#function): *** Error unable to get receipt expiredDate or convert it to a Date(), skipped")
                return
            }

            // This receipt is most recent than the currently stored? if, yes, replace
            if red.isAfter(ed) {
                content = receipt
                expiredDate = red


                // Is in trial?
                if let tp = content["is_trial_period"] as? String {
                    inFreeTrialPeriod = tp == "true"

                    if inFreeTrialPeriod {
                        haveBeenInFreeTrialPeriod = true
                    }
                }

                // When was the intro?
                if let intro = content["is_in_intro_offer_period"] as? String,
                    intro == "true" {
                    introOfferPeriodDate = red
                }


                let now = Date()

                // Subscription still active today?
                isActive = red.isAfterOrSame(now)

                // Eligibility; check against PREVIOUS subscription period
                if !isActive {
                   // You can use “is_in_intro_offer_period” value to determine if the user is eligible for introductory pricing. If a previous subscription period in the receipt has the value “true” for either the “is_trial_period” or “is_in_intro_offer_period” keys, the user is not eligible for a free trial or introductory price within that subscription group.
                    let benefitedFromIntroductoryPrice = introOfferPeriodDate != nil || haveBeenInFreeTrialPeriod
                    isEligible = !benefitedFromIntroductoryPrice
                }

            }
            print("\(#function): new \(self)")
        }
    }


    init(receipt: NSDictionary) {
        content = receipt

        if let productID = receipt["product_id"] as? String {
            self.productID = productID
        }

        // When subscription, set expires date
        if let receiptExpiresDate = receipt["expires_date"] as? String,
            let red = StoreKit.getDate(receiptExpiresDate) {
            expiredDate = red

            // Is in trial?
            if let tp = content["is_trial_period"] as? String,
                tp == "true" {
                inFreeTrialPeriod = true
                haveBeenInFreeTrialPeriod = true
            }

            // When was the intro?
            if let intro = content["is_in_intro_offer_period"] as? String,
                intro == "true" {
                introOfferPeriodDate = red
            }


            let now = Date()

            // Subscription still active today?
            isActive = red.isAfterOrSame(now)

            // Eligibility; check against PREVIOUS subscription period
            if !isActive {
                // You can use “is_in_intro_offer_period” value to determine if the user is eligible for introductory pricing. If a previous subscription period in the receipt has the value “true” for either the “is_trial_period” or “is_in_intro_offer_period” keys, the user is not eligible for a free trial or introductory price within that subscription group.
                let benefitedFromIntroductoryPrice = introOfferPeriodDate != nil || inFreeTrialPeriod
                isEligible = !benefitedFromIntroductoryPrice
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, would have have any sort of idea regarding my situation? I have an existing app with an auto-renewable IAP included live in the app store. I now added an introductory price on iTunes and I'm testing with a sandbox user. I have used this user to purchase the subscription with the full amount in my previous version. But now when I check the receipt, for the `is_in_intro_offer_period`, I get `true`. Even though I just implemented introductory offers and this user never purchased an introductory offer earlier. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If you implemented IAP introductory prices correctly you should not need to do any extra work on the iOS side to manage it. The prices are managed through the iTunesConnect interface. By implementing it correctly I mean using SKProduct APIs to get the price and display it in the app so that when you change it from iTunes connect it also changes in the app.